# Cable unplugged after NeoRouter connection disabled once

Tags: windows, vpn, network-adapter

Network adapters can be disabled and then enabled again in Windows.

This doesn't work for the NeoRouter network adapter, which is a VPN shell.

What happens is that once disabled, this adapter can't be enabled again and its status remains forever as `Network cable unplugged`. Only reboot can help.

Is there any way to fix this?

**UPDATE**

Windows in Windows 8 Professional 64 bit

Internet sharing is OFF.

Comment: What is your Windows version and is it 32- or 64-bit? Is ICS (internet connection Sharing) enabled ?

Comment: See also how to generate a log file in the [NeoRouterWiki:FAQ](http://www.neorouter.com/wiki/index.php/NeoRouterWiki:FAQ#How_to_generate_a_log_file.3F) that can help you understand the problem, or add the file to your post if you want us to have a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm experiencing this problem too where NR virtual adapter indicates "Network cable unplugged" and (partially) stops working. This has happened to me twice in as many weeks, even though I haven't disabled the Neorouter (NR) adapter to cause the state!

In this state, the NR client still connects over the internet to the NR server, but I cannot ping any of the computers on the NR network or browse files, remote access, etc. I've tried to change Media status to "always connected" in the adapter advanced configuration, but this does not fix the issue, even though the "Network cable unplugged" warning now disappears.

To fix the issue I have to uninstall and choose to delete all files), then re install.

I assume I'm using the 32-bit version (because it's installed in Program Files (x86) - this is installed on a 64-bit version of Windows 8.1.